# How to append NBA player NAMES with STATS?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, append, concatenation

I am still learning web scraping and could use some help please. I would like to get NBA team stats for each player by combining 3 different dataframes: playerNames, playerStats_one, playerStats_two.

Here is an example of the dataframe that I am looking for:

```
Name                GP   MIN   PTS   ...

Anthony Davis       62   34.4  26.1  ...

Lebron James        67   34.6  25.3  ...

Kyle Kuzma          61   25.0  12.8  ...

...                 ...   ...   ...
```

Here is my code so far:

```
import pandas as pd

import requests

url = 'https://www.espn.com/nba/team/stats/_/name/lal/season/2020/seasontype/2'
df = pd.read_html(url)



#goal 1 get player names

playerNames = df[0]


#goal 2 get stats

playerStats_one = df[1]
playerStats_two = df[3]


#goal 3 append or concat player stats to player name dataframe

new_df = pd.concat([playerNames, playerStats_one, playerStats_two], ignore_index=True, sort=False)

new_df2 = playerNames.append(playerStats_one, ignore_index=True)
```

I tried to use pd.concat and the append option and the output had a bunch of 'nan' values. Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance for any insight you may offer.

Comment: `pd.concat([df[0], df[1], df[3]], axis=1)`

Comment: Thank you so much @Quang Hoang for taking the time to help me. Would you like to answer that so that I can mark it as the best answer?

Comment: You're welcome. Happy coding.